# Creating trial tenant in Microsoft 365 / Office 365 is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-platform

I had a trial Office 365 tenant that expired recently. But I am able to access the Microsoft 365 admin center, Power Automate, and Power Apps, but not SharePoint Online. Is there any way I can access SharePoint Online with my expired tenant? I think my tenant is not expired, as I am able to access other resources mentioned above using the same tenant URL.

Now, I am trying to subscribe using this [URL](https://signup.microsoft.com/get-started/signup?OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK&ali=1&products=cfq7ttc0k59j%3A0009&brandingId=28b276fb-d2a0-4379-a7c0-57dce33da0f9), after completing all steps, at the final step, it shows that a tenant cannot be created for this account. I have used a new email address and mobile number.

Then, I have tried with the second [URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/office-365-e3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), where it is mandatory to update the credit card number. The first month would be free, and from the second month onwards, an automatic amount will be deducted from the credit card.

I am really frustrated now. I just want to learn and explore new features in Microsoft 365 and share the knowledge with the community, but Microsoft is applying so much restriction to users. At the end of the day, it is good for Microsoft, right? We are promoting their products (by exploring their features and sharing them with the community) so that they can increase their revenue.

Any lead from Microsoft or anywhere can help me out on this. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining the Microsoft 365 developer program, which will give you a free tenant for development purposes. This will allow you to do all the testing required, and as long as you're using it frequently enough, your developer subscription will renew.

[Microsoft 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it for 90 days free trial or beyond that? If I use it frequently, will it be active for ever? Does this contain SharePoint, Power Automate, Power Apps, Teams etc?

Comment: It renews every 90 days, as long as you are using the tenant for development purposes often. It contains E5 licences for all of those products, yes.

Comment: Wow, I will try and update you, thank you so much for letting me know this mate. :-)